# Proxying a CAS Service with CASClient and Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, cas

my first question at SO, hope I can get any help.

The architecture of the problem is: I have a simple webapp sourced by Sinatra and Slim, and using SSO CAS System for Authentication. Importand detail: Not using Rails.

The CAS filter is done by hand like this:

> ```
> class App < Sinatra::Application
>
> before do
> process_cas_login(request, session)
> require_authorization(request, session) unless logged_in?(request, session)      end
> ```

And the CAS methods do something like this:

> def process_cas_login(request, session)
>       if request[:ticket] && request[:ticket] != session[:ticket]
>
> ```
>   service_url = read_service_url(request)
>   st = read_ticket(request[:ticket], service_url)
>
>   CAS_CLIENT.validate_service_ticket(st)
>
>   if st.success
>     session[:cas_ticket] = st.ticket
>     session[:cas_user] = st.user
>   else
>     redirect '/'
>     #raise "Service Ticket validation failed! #{st.failure_code} - #{st.failure_message}"
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> end
>
> def logged_in?(request, session)
>       session[:cas_ticket] && !session[:cas_ticket].empty?   end
>
> def require_authorization(request, session)
>       if !logged_in?(request, session)
>         service_url = read_service_url(request)
>         url = CAS_CLIENT.add_service_to_login_url(service_url)
>         redirect url
>       end   end

The problem is: My backend needs to invoke a REST service from other Sinatra application and mantain the session (ask for a ticket, know the user that invoked that service, stuff like that)

I was reading about Proxying but I couldn't make that happen in my current model, do you have any clues?

There is a walkthrough with Rails filters, but again, I am not using Rails.

Thank you on advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

In your app, instead of calling the service validate url, you need to call the proxy validate url of the CAS server (/proxyValidate) with your current `ticket`, the `service` and a `pgtUrl` parameter.
In the returned XML, you will get a new `cas:proxyGrantingTicket` tag containing the PGTIOU: it must be stored in a shared map in your app: `pgtIou` <-> user_identity

This `pgtUrl` is an url in your application which will receives callbacks from the CAS server with two parameters: `pgtIou` and `pgtId`.  Using the previous shared map, you know have: `pgtId` <-> user_identity.

For a user identity, if you want to call a REST service, you need to obtain a ticket for it by calling the /proxy url of the CAS server giving the `pgt` parameter (the pgtId) and a `targetService` parameter for the REST service.

Finally, you just need to call your REST service like any CAS service by providing a service ticket. This REST service must protected by the CAS server of course and will in turn perform a service ticket validation via the CAS server.